# База данных АПИ Андроид

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! Каждый раз когда дело касается работы с базой данных, которая размещена не в девайсе, а  где-то лежит на хостинге, всегда приходится писать на php какой-то апи для обработки данных и работы с базой.А потом получать json, парсить и вытаскивать нужные данные. Это напряжно. 
Есть ли какое-то готовое решение? или готовые библиотеки или облако?

обычно делаю таким образом.

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

а потом вот так использую:

```
try {
                    url_product_detials = "http://*************/*******/get_product_details.php";
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON
                                                                            // Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    name = product.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    text = product.getString(TAG_TEXT);

                } else {
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: так как ни кто не знает, что за данные вам вздумается перегонять через интернет, готового решения нет.    
Максимум, что может быть - API, который примет запрос в строковом виде, и отдаст результат в каком ни будь виде...
но это просто до беспредела небезопасно, да и выгода от такого решения очень сомнительная, даже если опустить безопасность...

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле это не "напряжно". Вебсервис вы можете писать на чем угодно (не обязательно php), главное чтобы грамотно выполнял требуемые задачи. В свою очередь JSON - отличный формат данных с нативным парсингом в Android. Поэтому это действительно хороший вариант! Если надо работать с большим объемом различных данных, да и еще в пределах одного запроса - посмотрите в сторону JSONrpc.

Comment: ок, посмотрю JSONrpc

Comment: JSONrpc - только в случае необходимости в одном запросе обрабатывать большое количество РАЗЛИЧНЫХ данных. Для основных вещей JSON со всем справится!

Comment: просто с JSON я уже работал несколько раз, но все-равно кажется что, можно написать либу которая сократит колличество кода.

Comment: На самом деле JSON и является тем средством, чтобы сократить работу)) Представьте что у вас нет в расспоряжении всех методов как optString ... и других. Парсить руками было бы очень сложно. Может вам стоит пересмотреть то, как именно вы взаимодействуете с Json?

Comment: создаю класс jsonParser,потом им пользуюсь. сейчас добавлю в вопрос код

Answer (score 0):

Если база не будет менятся, то можно ее скачивать с сервера в формате sqlite.

Если база будет менятся 1-2 раза в неделю, то тоже можно скачивать с сервера.

По сути json нужен что бы быстро получать изменения.

Также можно попробовать передавать нужный тебе параметр на сервер и что бы сам сервер делал фильтрацию.